# Nginx backend shutdown without losing sessions

Tags: nginx

So I'm having reverse proxy server, where Nginx working as proxy server and loadbalancer. My biggest problem, that I have 2 app backends, which I need sometimes to shutdown. When I write after server ***down*** the backend, shutdown and looses sessions. How can I gracefully shutdown one of my app server? So that Nginx wait while all sessions will be completed or for some time?

My simple config:

```
upstream loadbalancer {
                ip_hash;
                server          192.168.0.1:443;
                server          192.168.0.2:443;
}
```

Comment: Please ask this on [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue is that each server has it's own session manager, and when the server is dead the session data is lost with that server, a good solution is to make a centralized session storage, for example the same server which is load balancing, and the other 2 servers connect to it to get the session data, if one server is down, and the other server tries to serve the connection that was being served by the other server then the data will still be found because the data is stored elsewhere, common methods to do so is using memcached as session storage.

As for the pros, you can add and remove as much app servers as you want and the users won't even notice any change.

But for the cons, if that single server dies, all session data is lost, because the data is centralized.

You haven't really tagged your question with what language you are using, but if you search for it on google you'll easily find useful posts to help you.

Comment: It's not a problem that when server die it will lost sessions. When I have maintenance with one of app servers I want to tell Nginx that it will not give new sessions to server nr. 2, but give all new sessions to server nr. 1, and all old sessions in server in nr. 2 must stay until they expired.

Comment: ok so another idea don't mark server as down, just decrease it's priority, i don't know if it will keep the old sessions connected to the original server or not.

Comment: When decreasing priority, Nginx starts to deliver old sessions request to new server (with higher priority) even if I have ip_hash.